# Angular 4 can't find component created inside a module

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a pretty simple question.

I created a new angular project using the cli. I then created a module and component called home-page. Within homepage, I created a component called banner.

My main application can import the  component just fine. But home page can't seem to import .

Here's my project structure :

```
├── app.component.html
├── app.component.sass
├── app.component.spec.ts
├── app.component.ts
├── app.module.ts
├── home-page
│   ├── banner
│   │   ├── banner.component.html
│   │   ├── banner.component.sass
│   │   ├── banner.component.spec.ts
│   │   └── banner.component.ts
│   ├── home-page.component.html
│   ├── home-page.component.sass
│   ├── home-page.component.spec.ts
│   ├── home-page.component.ts
│   └── home-page.module.ts
└── simple-grid.scss
```

Here's the home-page.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.sass']
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here's the home-page.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    BannerComponent,
    HomePageComponent
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

home-page.component.html:

```
<div>
  <banner></banner>

</div>
```

banner.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.sass']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

banner.component.html:

```
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 center"><p>1</p></div>
    <div class="col-4 center"><p>2</p></div>
    <div class="col-4 center"><p>3</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know this type of question has been asked before, but they looked like they were asking about stranger imports. I think mine should be a lot more basic, so I'd like to know which step I missed or if I have a typo or something.

Thanks

Comment: `BannerComponent` is in which module. update the code for `module` definitions

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm not sure if you're asking a question for giving me a solution though.

Comment: Banner is a component inside the home-page module. Home-page is also a component. Hope that helps.

Comment: so you are using `HomePageModule` in  your main module?

Comment: Yeah, and that seems to be working just fine.

Comment: so my answer works or not?

Comment: Um... I think I'm having trouble understanding you. The home page module has always worked inside of the main module. I'm unable to import the banner component into the home page module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148146/discussion-between-aravind-and-maz).

Comment: waited for a long time in chat. ping me in fb @ aravind2109. will help you to fix this

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an `export` statement in your `HomePageModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BannerComponent } from './banner/banner.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './home-page.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    BannerComponent,
    HomePageComponent
  ],
/////////////// added  below    ////////////////////////////////////
exports: [
    BannerComponent,
    HomePageComponent
  ]
})
export class HomePageModule { }
```

Comment: It took me an hour to figure this out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

So Basically,

I was importing home-page.component into app.module and couldn't get banner.component to load because the home-page.component wasn't exporting it.

Importing home-page.module into app.module allowed me export its child components and worked without issue.

reposting the file structure for clarity:

```
├── app.component.html
├── app.component.sass
├── app.component.spec.ts
├── app.component.ts
├── app.module.ts
├── home-page
│   ├── banner
│   │   ├── banner.component.html
│   │   ├── banner.component.sass
│   │   ├── banner.component.spec.ts
│   │   └── banner.component.ts
│   ├── home-page.component.html
│   ├── home-page.component.sass
│   ├── home-page.component.spec.ts
│   ├── home-page.component.ts
│   └── home-page.module.ts
└── simple-grid.scss
```

TLDR; I lack experience with this framework and I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issues are so petty that we do not care to look into that.

Check whether folder names are proper or not. Path provided in the module.ts for importing that component is proper or not.

e.g. `import { SomeComponent } from './Some-Folder/';`
However, SomeComponent is present in 'some-folder' not in 'Some-Folder' then it can give that issue.  Character case must be same.

In windows, it may compile successfully but in linux environment it will definitely fail.

Provided this answers to those who have spent hours for this issue and came here after seeing the issue mentioned in the header.

Hope this is helpful to someone.

P.S. Just make sure to create the component using cli command only. It will save others valuable time.